# Specifying parameters for SARIMAX model with significant ACF / PACF at tails

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, acf-pacf, differencing

I have hourly data that has a period of 1 day or 24 hours / time steps and I hope to do short term forecasting for a few days in advance. The ACF of the raw time series was periodic (see last figure) like [from this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/314456/what-can-be-done-in-case-with-periodic-acf), so I took a difference between the series and a shifted series by 24 timesteps. The differenced series has an ACF and PACF below.

My confusion is that both ACF and PACF shows decreasing / low significance until hour 20ish after which the magnitude of the significance increases. I'm wondering how to correctly specify the parameters (or range of parameters for a search) for a SARIMA model or is there further processing I should try? Should I consider including lags up to 23 hours for both MA and AR components or will that overfit?

[image]

[image]

Edit: The ACF of the raw target

[image]

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to select your own model, rather than having established tools do this for you? https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/595150/1352 Also, what do you plan on doing with your model? Do you want to forecast, or analyze it in some way? Third, where does your data come from? Many hourly time series exhibit [tag:multiple-seasonalities], with hour-of-week *and* hour-of-day patterns, which plan vanilla SARIMA was not built for.

Comment: You might have overdifferenced your data, as the autocorrelation at lag 24 is now negative. Are you sure the data was seasonally integrated? If not, taking seasonal differences might have been a bad idea.

Comment: @StephanKolassa  I added the ACF of the raw target for a week; I'm not sure how to spot a weekly pattern but I only have a few months of data so I don't think I can detect longer term patterns. I am hoping to use this for short term forecasting (a few days in advance). I prefer using a moving window validation method instead of using an automated method with information criterion but even in the latter I would need to figure out parameter upper bound in the search.

Comment: @RichardHardy I added the ACF of the raw target, it looked similar to the plot from [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/314456/what-can-be-done-in-case-with-periodic-acf) and one of the answers suggested that the model has yearly seasonality from the plot.

Comment: @Yandle, presence of yearly seasonality does not warrant differencing at the corresponding frequency, though many commit the mistake of thinking and doing so. Compare to an AR(1) model: when first-order partial autocorrelation is nonzero, generally you do not difference; you fit an AR(1) model instead.

Comment: @RichardHardy So in this case the seasonal parameters (P,D,Q,S) should be something like (1,0,?,24) instead of (0,1,?,24) since the ACF of the seasonally differenced plot shows negative correlation?

Comment: (1) If it's the orders of the SARIMA model you are concerned about, [the defaults in `auto.arima()`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/285093/1352) are based on the experience of some of the best forecasters I know. Yes, your specific situation may call for different orders... but I would always start with what these people think makes sense. (2) If your interest is mainly in forecasting, do consider other methods than SARIMA, like seasonal exponential smoothing, it is frequently quite competitive.

Comment: (3) Hour-of-week patterns may be quite visible with even only a few months of data. Do consider specialized methods for multiple seasonalities (again, because you seem to be mainly interested in forecasting). TBATS is state of the art here (and note that it includes automatic SARIMA order selection), and is also quite slow. I have found STLF decomposition as well as a very straightforward multiple regression with dummies for day of week in an interaction with harmonics for hour of day to be very good *and* fast. Reach out to me for a presentation at the last ISF if you are interested.