# Auto correlation function in R what are the error lines

Tags: r, time-series

If one invokes acf() function in R the estimated acf values are plotted together with blue error lines. What are they (the lines)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has been answered before [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49571/understanding-the-blue-dotted-lines-in-an-acf-from-r). They represent statistical significance, where the null hypothesis is:

$$H_0: r_k=0$$

The test statistic is:

$$\mid r_k\mid>\frac{1.96}{\sqrt{n}}$$

See Cowpertait & Metcalfe (2009) for more about time series analysis in `R`.